# Syncfusion how to get file details after upload in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion, asyncfileupload, ej2-syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion `File Uploader` and I want to get file details like new file name after upload. But apparently there is no way to get the uploaded file information.

```
@{
    var asyncSettings = new Syncfusion.EJ2.Inputs.UploaderAsyncSettings { SaveUrl = "/Student/Save" };
}

<ejs-uploader id="UploadFiles" asyncSettings="@asyncSettings" dropArea=".control-fluid" multiple=false autoUpload=false></ejs-uploader>
```

And in `StudentController`, I have this method:

```
  public void Save(IList<IFormFile> UploadFiles)
  {
      //File upload code
      Response.Headers.Add("documentname", newFileName);
  }
```

The name of the file before uploading to the server is changed in a variable named `newFileName` and I want to have this name in the client.

Note: the uploader (`ejs-uploader`) is in a modal form and the page should not be refreshed

Comment: you would set that in your code.  When the file is uploaded it is placed in a temporary file/folder on the server.  You would then decide what to do with it.  (where to store/copy to, what filename to use when storing... you could use the filename value sent with the form, but that's usually a bad idea for many reasons.... security concerns, uniqueness, etc...)